# barchart with x-axis between 0 and 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a very silly problem and I don't know why it is happening. I only try to create a very simple bar chart but the result is not what expected:

```
import operator
hist = {1.0: 16173, 0.99: 2597, 0.98: 1162, 0.97: 765, 0.96: 533, 0.95: 422, 0.94: 369, 0.93: 280, 0.92: 258, 0.91: 231, 0.9: 207, 0.89: 199, 0.88: 184, 0.87: 177, 0.86: 155, 0.85: 152, 0.84: 140, 0.83: 140, 0.82: 126, 0.81: 116, 0.8: 113, 0.77: 105, 0.79: 97, 0.75: 94, 0.71: 94, 0.76: 86, 0.65: 85, 0.72: 85, 0.74: 83, 0.63: 83, 0.54: 82, 0.66: 77, 0.52: 77, 0.59: 76, 0.78: 76, 0.73: 75, 0.68: 75, 0.53: 73, 0.55: 73, 0.69: 72, 0.7: 72, 0.58: 72, 0.57: 70, 0.62: 70, 0.6: 68, 0.67: 64, 0.51: 63, 0.64: 61, 0.56: 59, 0.61: 50, 0.5: 34}

total = sum(hist.values())
sorted_seq = sorted(hist.iteritems(), key= operator.itemgetter(0))
x = [i[0] for i in sorted_seq]
y = [i[1]/float(total) for i in sorted_seq]
plt.figure() 
ax = plt.subplot()
bins = ax.bar(x,y,align='center')

ax.set_ylim((min(y),max(y)+0.01))
ax.autoscale(True,'x',True)
```

x axis should be limited to 0 and 1.but still going further with very wired look. using `ax.set_xlim(0,1)` didn't fix the problem. any idea why it's happening?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to give `ax.bar` the `width` argument, otherwise it is set to a default of 0.8

```
bins = ax.bar(x,y,width=0.01,align='center')
```

[image]

The reason you have  `xmax = 1.4` when you don't set `width` is because of the `align = 'center'` (meaning that your `xmax` is `1 + 0.8/2 = 1.4`)

Answer (score -1):

I think it was the autoscale that overrides the `set_xlim` command. Also, careful, xlim takes a tuple (like set_ylim!). Here's the code I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import operator

from collections import Counter

hist = Counter({1.0: 16173, 0.99: 2597, 0.98: 1162, 0.97: 765, 0.96: 533, 0.95: 422, 0.94: 369, 0.93: 280, 0.92: 258, 0.91: 231, 0.9: 207, 0.89: 199, 0.88: 184, 0.87: 177, 0.86: 155, 0.85: 152, 0.84: 140, 0.83: 140, 0.82: 126, 0.81: 116, 0.8: 113, 0.77: 105, 0.79: 97, 0.75: 94, 0.71: 94, 0.76: 86, 0.65: 85, 0.72: 85, 0.74: 83, 0.63: 83, 0.54: 82, 0.66: 77, 0.52: 77, 0.59: 76, 0.78: 76, 0.73: 75, 0.68: 75, 0.53: 73, 0.55: 73, 0.69: 72, 0.7: 72, 0.58: 72, 0.57: 70, 0.62: 70, 0.6: 68, 0.67: 64, 0.51: 63, 0.64: 61, 0.56: 59, 0.61: 50, 0.5: 34})

total = sum(hist.values())
sorted_seq = sorted(hist.iteritems(), key= operator.itemgetter(0))
x = [int(i[0]) for i in sorted_seq]
print(x)
y = [i[1]/float(total) for i in sorted_seq]
print(y)
plt.figure() 
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
bins = ax.bar(x,y,align='center')

ax.set_ylim((min(y),max(y)+0.01))
ax.set_xlim((0, 1))
ax.set_xlabel('conf',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('freq',fontsize=15)
#ax.autoscale(True,'x',True)

plt.show()
```

And the result is:

[image]

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: but your plot also doesn't look ok. y value increases as x goes to one. I don't know why some bar have similar/missing values in your plot

Comment: well, your x list looks like 

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

which if I'm correct means you'll only get 2 bars, since all the x's are at the same position, save for the last. And the height of your first bar will be max(y[:-1]). Are you sure you want to do that typecast to int in the x generator expression?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't have the `int` in the x generator that you have in your answer, which is where your problem is